# Имитация перехода на сторонний сайт

Tags: php

Существует ли решение в php( кроном или при загрузки страницы пользователем), переход на страницу для поисковой системы стороннего сайта. То есть которая фиксирует переход со страницы вашего сайта на другой сайт, без участия реального человека?

Comment: Уточните Ваш вопрос - покажите на примере, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Хочется, что бы поисковые системы определяли, что  пользователь перешёл с моего сайта на сторонний сайт. Так вообще возможно?)

Comment: Вообще нет, но можно косвенно. Если на сайте есть система аналитики - например Яндекс Метрика, то она зафиксирует переход на сайт с другого сайта. Но для этого нужен а) полноценный эмулятор браузера б) неизвестно насколько ПС это учитывают.